# Understanding garbage collector behavior for a local variable

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Below is a very simple console app (try the [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/NXMPDI)):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ConsoleApp
{
    class Callback
    {
        public Callback() { }
        ~Callback() { Console.WriteLine("~Callback"); }
    }

    static void Test(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Callback callback = new Callback();

        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // for the GC
            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        // no need for KeepAlive?
        // GC.KeepAlive(callback);      
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(3000);
        try
        {
            Test(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here, the `callback` object doesn't get garbage-collected until it goes out of scope of the `Test` method.

I thought `GC.KeepAlive(callback)` would be required to keep it alive inside `Test` (as [MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but apparently it is not (commented out in the code above).

Now if I change the code like below, the `callback` does get garbage-collected, as expected:

```
Callback callback = new Callback();
callback = null;
```

This happens with .NET 4.5.1.

**The question**: Am I missing something? Can I rely upon this behavior, or is it something .NET version specific?

Comment: Try building & running it in Release mode, without the debugger attached. I get the expected behaviour there but not in Debug.

Comment: @Porges, the same behavior for Debug and Release build.

Comment: Without the debugger? ie. running with Ctrl-F5, not just F5. It collects it instantly for me in each of .NET 4/4.5/4.5.1. But yes, you can't really rely on this behaviour.

Comment: @Porges, that was it! Release build, Ctrl-F5 did it. I'd up-vote and accept it if you posted it as an answer. Apparently, the [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/NXMPDI) also runs with the debugger attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Porges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10311/porges)' comments explain everything very well:

> Try building & running it in Release mode, without the debugger attached. I get the expected behaviour there but not in Debug.
>   ...
>   ie. running with Ctrl-F5, not just F5. It collects it instantly for me in each of .NET 4/4.5/4.5.1. But yes, you can't really rely on this behaviour.

The Release build and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> brought back the expected behavior. **I urge @Porges to post this as an answer**, which I'd up-vote and accept with thanks.

As a follow-up, I'd like to feature the following interesting behavior. Now with Release + Ctrl-F5, even if I un-comment the `// GC.KeepAlive(callback)` line in my code, the `callback` still gets garbage-collected. Apparently, this is because the compiler recognizes this line as unreachable due to `while (true)` loop and still doesn't emit a strong reference on `callback`.

The following is the correct pattern:

```
static void Test(CancellationToken token)
{
    Callback callback = new Callback();

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // for the GC
            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.KeepAlive(callback);     
    }
}
```

It's also interesting to look at the `GC.KeepAlive` implementation:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static void KeepAlive(object obj)
{
}
```

As expected, it does nothing and merely servers as a hint to the compiler to generate IL code which keeps a strong reference to the object, up to the point where `KeepAlive` is called. `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` is very relevant here to prevent any optimizations like above.

Comment: I'd like to point out that finalizers are somewhat separate from garbage collection in general - the object might be partially (or completely!) garbage collected before the finalizer is even called - that's why you must not use any of the managed objects in the class in the finalizer - they aren't necessarily there anymore. One way to check if the object was GC'd (not finalized) is to create a weak `GCHandle` to it - it will not prevent the garbage collection, but it will allow you to check if the object has been collected (the handle will be zeroed).

Comment: @Luaan, it's a good point and that's why I put `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` there. Although I'd use `WeakReference` (and `WeakReference.IsAlive`) if I needed to track GC'ed objects in real life project.

Answer (score 1):

.NET garbage collection is non-deterministic.

The [MSDN page to which you linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says it all really - emphasis added:

> The purpose of the KeepAlive method is to ensure the existence of a reference to an object that is *at risk* of being prematurely reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Just because `callback` can be garbage collected before it goes out of scope on return from `Test` does not mean that it will be.