# .NET 6.0/7.0: How to force garbage collection of local variables?

Tags: c#, .net-core

**[PURPOSE]**

I need to use reflections to

1. Load an assembly into a **separate ApplicationLoadContext**
2. Create a type from it
3. Create an instance from the type
4. Invoke functions on the instance repeatedly
5. After some time, perhaps days, when this assembly is no longer needed, **unload the ApplicationLoadContext then delete the assembly file**.

If you want to know why I am doing this, please see skybridge.net.au.

**[The problem]**

Although I have set all references to the assembly, type and instances to null before unloading the ApplicationLoadContext, it still failed to unload.

**[Code demo 1]**

The following code shows how my code works. It failed to delete the DLL file:

```
namespace MyDll
{
    public class MyText
    {
        public string m_text;

        public MyText(string text)
        {
            m_text = text;
        }

        public string GetText()
        {
            return m_text;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string GetTextByBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyText>(json);
            return obj.GetText();
        }

        public string GetTextByObject(MyText text)
        {
            return text.GetText();
        }

        public string GetGuidText(Guid guid)
        {
            return guid.ToString();
        }

        public string GetText(string str)
        {
            return str;
        }

        public List<string> GetMultipleTexts(List<string> lst)
        {
            return lst;
        }

    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new AssemblyLoadContext(null, isCollectible: true);

        var assembly = ctx.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllFilePath);
        var myType = assembly.GetType("MyDll.MyClass");
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, new object[] { }, null);
        var myMethod = myType.GetMethod("GetGuidText");
        var res = myMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { Guid.NewGuid() });

        assembly = null;
        myType = null;
        instance = null;
        myMethod = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        ctx.Unload();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        File.Delete(dllFilePath);          
        Console.WriteLine($"Done!");
    }
```

**[Code demo 2]**

But, if I **put the code in a separate function**, Test(), the deletion works:

```
    private static void Test(AssemblyLoadContext ctx)
    {
        var assembly = ctx.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllFilePath);
        var myType = assembly.GetType("MyDll.MyClass");
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, new object[] { }, null);
        var myMethod = myType.GetMethod("GetGuidText");
        var res = myMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { Guid.NewGuid() });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new AssemblyLoadContext(null, isCollectible: true);
        Test(ctx);
        ctx.Unload();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        File.Delete(dllFilePath);         
        Console.WriteLine($"Done!");
    }
```

**[But I can't change my code to the demo 2 style]**

In my SkyBridge app, the loaded assembly and the types and instances loaded from this assembly are placed into a global collection, to be invoked by a separate thread. So I can't put them into a function as local variables and let them go out of scope when that function exits, like in **[Code demo 2]**.

Instead, when an assembly is no longer needed, all I can do is like **[Code demo 1]**, to remove them from the global collection, set their references to null, and hope GC can collect them so I can unload and delete. But it always fails.

**[Final Question]**

Is there anything that I can do in **[Code demo 1]** to enable the unloading and deletion, without putting the types and instances into a function as local variables?

********* Added on 2023-06-02 **********

Now the problem becomes clearer. If a local variable is declared in a function, when that function ends, that variable goes out of scope. When I call GC.Collect, it is immediately collected. However, if this variable is a global variable that never goes out of scope, even if I set it to null then call GC.Collect, it is not collected.

**Is there a way to force a global variable that never goes out of scope to be immediately collected after GC.Collect?**

Comment: why dont you implement IDisposable at class level ?

Comment: I did. But in the Dispose method all I can do is to set the references to the assembly and types to null. They are not disposable. It still doesn't work because the code is still like [code demo 1]. The classes are all global, not a local variable in a method that goes out of scope.

Comment: since i found this really interesting please tell me why first approach i replicated with your code and  it worked? i mean no errors with your snippet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding garbage collector behavior for a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495819/understanding-garbage-collector-behavior-for-a-local-variable)

Comment: You need to put the code that uses those variables into a separate function if you are in Debug mode

Comment: jmvcollaborator: please read the introduction of my website skybridge.net.au to see why I am doing this. [Code demo 1] kept failing on my end.

Comment: Charlieface: I tried in release mode and the behavior is still the same: setting a local variable to null does not cause it to be garbage collected.