# Is there a simple way to return a task with an exception?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

My understanding is that `return Task.FromResult(foo)` is a simple shorthand for:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TFoo>();
tcs.SetResult(foo);
return tcs.Task;
```

Is there some equivalent for a task that returns an exception state?

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TFoo>();
tcs.SetException(new NotSupportedException()); // or whatever is appropriate
return tcs.Task;
```

I don't see anything like `Task.FromException`.   Or would it be more appropriate to just throw the exception without returning a task?

Comment: Looking at your code makes me want to select it and use "Extract Method" in ReSharper.

Comment: It appears that such a method was intentionally not exposed: it exists, but is `internal`.

Comment: The trouble with that approach is that the exception you return wouldn't have a stack trace, since it is never actually thrown. Perhaps that's why the FromException is not exposed.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Sure, I can put it in a method, but I'm more interested if this is the right approach or not.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - Hmmm.. so should I throw it, catch it and then return it in the Task?  I don't think it should just be thrown.  Or should it?

Comment: @MattJohnson, well, throwing it just to catch it doesn't seem a very good idea... I guess Noseratio's answer is a good solution

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting with .NET 4.6 there is a [`Task.FromException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the BCL.

There's also [`Task.FromCanceled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.fromcanceled(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 14):

> My understanding is that return Task.FromResult(foo) is a simple
>   shorthand for... [`TaskCompletionSource.SetResult`].

Actually, `Task.FromResult` doesn't use `TaskCompletionSource`, [its implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs#a8716bfd172d077c) is much simpler than that.

> Is there some equivalent for a task that returns an exception state?

I reckon `TaskCompletionSource` would be the best option for this. You could also do something like this:

```
static Task FromExAsync(Exception ex) 
{
    var task = new Task(() => { throw ex; });
    task.RunSynchronously();
    return task;
}
```

The exception will not be propagated outside the returned `task`, until observed via `await task` or `task.Wait()`, which should be a desired behavior.

Note that if the exception passed to `FromExAsync` is an active exception (i.e. has been already thrown and caught elsewhere), re-throwing it like this would loose the current stack trace and Watson buckets information stored inside the exception. There are two ways of dealing with it:

- Wrap the exception with `AggregateException`. This will make the original exception available as `AggregateException.InnerException`:

```
static Task FromExAsync(Exception ex) 
{
    var task = new Task(() => { throw new AggregateException(ex); });
    task.RunSynchronously();
    return task;
}
```

- Use `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture` to flow the active exception's state:

```
static Task FromExAsync(Exception ex) 
{
    var ei = System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
    var task = new Task(() => { ei.Throw(); });
    task.RunSynchronously();
    return task;
}
```

Finally, perhaps the simplest yet the worst option (due to the [overhead of the state machine](http://pastebin.com/qc1wLhEr) and the compiler warning) is to throw from an `async` method:

```
static async Task FromExAsync(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Given this talk of overhead, perhaps one could consider using a custom Awaiter?

Comment: @Aron, I don't see how a custom awaiter would eliminate `async` and the task machine, as @MattJohnson needs a `Task` object for the return value. For some extra details, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22268569/1768303).

Comment: Thanks.  Async programming is very powerful, but sometimes even the smallest things get confusing.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting is that `Task` has an internal `FromException` function, and that it internally uses the exact same `Task.TrySetException` function that `TaskCompletionSource.TrySetException` also uses. That's a strong reason for me to use `TaskCompletionSource.TrySetException`: you get the exact result that MS thinks is a good idea for `Task.FromException`.

Comment: @hvd, there's new `Task.FromException` API in .NET 4.6: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2015/02/02/new-task-apis-in-net-4-6.aspx

Comment: @Noseratio Heh, nice, thanks. I was looking at .NET 4.5, which does already have `FromException`, it just isn't public yet.